# Run for loop with sections of different behavior

Tags: bash

For example:
I have 100 folder names saved in a text file, how can I apply different command line in the same `for` loop for every 10 names?
In other words If I want to rename every 10 folders with a different name how can I apply the `mv` command in the same for loop for every 10 items in the text file?

```
#!/bin/bash -f
source=PATH TO THE DATA (100 FOLDERS)
for f in $(cat text.txt); do 
mv ${source}/"old folder name" ${source}/" new folder name"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have them in a text file, you could run two `for` loops with different index integers and address the files via their positions in the text file:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++ )) ; do
  newpos=$i_files
  for (( j=1 ; j<=10 ; j++ )) ; do
     mv "$( sed -n "$(( $i*10+$j ))p" filelist)" "$newpos"
  done
done
```

since it is about `mv` you can even use blocks of your input file with `sed`

```
 for (( i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++ )) ; do
    newpos=$i_files
    mv "$( sed -n "$(( $i*10+1 )),$(( ($i+1)*10 ))p" filelist)" "$newpos"
 done
```

Explanation on the `sed` part: `sed -n "4,8p" file` will print lines 4 through 8 of file.